# Gnome - Interface Text Font Weight

Tags: gnome, fonts

[image]

I've got my Interface Text, Document Text and Legacy Window Titles set to use either Medium or Bold variants of the San Francisco font, but as you can see from the side bar, it defaults to Regular. How do I get gnome to respect the choice of font weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue with Inter font, I wanted to use medium variant but regular was applied no matter what I pick. I could achieved it using gsettings from terminal, adding a comma between font name and size.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Inter Medium, 11'
```

Try it, it worked with medium variant but it didn't with light, also note that gnome Tweaks will show up as none font is selected.

Comment: Good to know. I solved it by only installing the fonts that had the weight I wanted, but I think this is a more flexible solution.

Comment: One specific roboto medium variant is know to work. The unhinted version in the repo does not. Above solution isnt working for me with SF Pro Display